# Constructors that do not duplicate code

Tags: c#

I have 2 constructor that have a base call in them as so;

```
public MyApplication(myEntities context)
            :base(context)
{
    _1stApp = new 1stApplication(this._context);
    _2ndApp = new 2ndApplication(this._context);
    // etc...
}

public MyApplication()
            :base()
{
    _1stApp = new 1stApplication(this._context);
    _2ndApp = new 2ndApplication(this._context);
    // etc...
}
```

along with the base constructors

```
public BaseApplication()
{
    _context= new myEntities ();
}

public BaseApplication(myEntities context)
{
    if (context==null)
        _context = context;
    else
        _context= new myEntities ();
}
```

inside the MyApplication constructors I either want to pass in a context that was created by another application or i want to create a new context.  in either case i want to share that same context with all the other application class's (1stApp,2ndApp,etc...) that MyApplication will be instantiating.

i dont want to have to keep same code in both places.

Answer (score 5):

```
public MyApplication(myEntities context)
        :base(context)
{
   _1stApp = new 1stApplication(this._context);
   _2ndApp = new 2ndApplication(this._context);
   etc...
}

public MyApplication()
    :this(new myEntities())
{ }
```

Comment: This is changing the functionality of the code; it's not equivalent.  You're now calling a different base constructor in the second case.  The base constructor could have dramatically different code in it.

Comment: I calls a different constructor - but the effect is the same - that _context is assigned.  The base constructor is shown above - and clearly doesn't have dramatically different code in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with only ONE c'tor (if you're using C# 3.5 or above). Just use an optional argument like this:

```
public MyApplication(myEntities context = null)
            :base(context)
    {

        _1stApp = new 1stApplication(this._context);
        _2ndApp = new 2ndApplication(this._context);
        etc...
    }

public BaseApplication(myEntities context)
        {
            if (context!=null)
                _context = context;
            else
                _context= new myEntities ();
        }
```

HTH Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Before the body of the constructor, use either:

For base class constructors use:

```
 : base (arguments)
```

For the same class, but another constructor, use:

```
 : this (arguments)
```

In your case, this `this` keywork:

```
public MyApplication(myEntities context)
        :base(context)
{
    // custom
}

public MyApplication()
     : this (new myEntities())
{
    _1stApp = new 1stApplication(this._context);
    _2ndApp = new 2ndApplication(this._context);
    etc...
}
```